# Core Data computed property updated, but view does not

Tags: swift, core-data

I have two entities 'First'(to-one) and 'Second'(to-many).

Parent view contains list of 'First':

```
@FetchRequest(
entity: First.entity(), 
sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \First.self, ascending: true)]
)
```

Also parent view contains Int number of 'seconds.archived' taken from computed property:

```
extension First {
    var archivedSeconds: Int {
        var count = 0
        seconds?.forEach { second in
            if (second as! Second).archived == true {
                count += 1
            }
        }
        return count
    }
}
```

Child view contains predicated list of 'Second' like 'seconds.archived'

```
@FetchRequest(
entity: Second.entity(), 
sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Second.self, ascending: true)], 
predicate: NSCompoundPredicate(type: NSCompoundPredicate.LogicalType.and, subpredicates: [
NSPredicate(format: "first == %@", first), 
NSPredicate(format: "archived == %@", NSNumber(value: true))])
)
```

When I change amount of 'seconds.archived' on child view, save changes and then come back to the parent view (via NavigationStack),

```
Text("\(first.archivedSeconds)")
```

isn't updating. I can update it by tapping on the tab in TabView. Looks like computed property 'archivedSeconds' of 'First' extension has been updated but my view has not.

How should I observe computed property in such a case?

Comment: Regular properties don't *publish*. You could use a transient property or call `objectWillChange` on the parent entity in the `willSet` property observer of `archived`. By the way `archivedSeconds` can be reduced to `(seconds as! Set<Second>).filter(\.arvchived).count`

Comment: All CoreData objects are ObservableObjects therefore they should be wrapped with “@ObservedObject”